# Where is the code that set the background image in TwentyTen theme?

Tags: theme-twenty-ten

I am developing a theme for my blog using Twenty Ten as starting point.

Now, I am trying to understand how it manages the background image that can be set in theme options but I wasn't able to find the code. Can you help find where is that implementation?

Comment: do you mean the code where background image is displayed or the code where the options is set in the theme?

Comment: @Amit I mean the code where background image is displayed, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is native WP feature, it is set up in Twenty Ten with simple [`add_custom_background()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_custom_background) call in `functions.php`.